# Sprite Kit: Physics Barrier iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, game-physics, sprite-kit

I have a player that sits at the bottom of the screen and is controlled by the accelerometer and i have baddies that drop from the roof. I have put a physics barrier around the screen

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

bud the baddies hit this barrier is there a way i can make them not collide with the barrier or just have a barrier either side and not on the top and bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you solved this or not, but I was having the same problem.  Baddies from the top, but needed to drop them from off screen, they kept hitting the top barrier.  So what I did was to extend my SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect.  I first made an offset to extend the top part of my rect.

```
float topOffset = 547.0;
```

This is how high above the top of the screen I made the bad guys.  Then I created my new frame with.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, -topOffset, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + topOffset);
```

Notice that for the height I had to add the topOffset so it wouldn't crash! Then I just applied the bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect.

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:newFrame];
```

This still leaves a bottom boundary, but you could extend that one as well if you wish.  Hope this helps someone, it took me a while to figure it out!!